# Total commander Hidden Directories do not show

Tags: windows-8.1-upgrade, total-commander, hidden-file

How can I make Windows Total Commander to show `hidden directories` ? When I type `AppData` a new window opens, but is not by default visible in the panels:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration -> Options -> Display -> "Show hidden files"